Java Gradle add a plugin (GraalVM) offline on a existent project
In order to convert a project to native-image I try to add the plugin "org.graalvm.buildtools.native". I specify that my pc is offline this is important, for various reasons I am obliged to use graalVM on an offline installation.
To be able to run my basic project I had to already compile it on an online installation, then I transferred the contents of the .gradle to this offline installation.
After a compilation on the offline installation the project run, the problem is not here.
To be able to install the plugin "org.graalvm.buildtools.native" I used this documentation:
https://graalvm.github.io/native-build-tools/latest/gradle-plugin.html
Which gives me the following build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'org.graalvm.buildtools.native' version '0.9.28'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'app-sonar'
}

allprojects {
    group = 'app.project'
}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '8.7'
    distributionUrl = "gradle-${gradleVersion}-bin.zip"
}

On an online computer I can compile the project again and download the plugin into my .gradle folder.
However, when I retransfer my .gradle from my online installation to my offline installation, the compilation does not work because it cannot find this plugin.
I got this error :
Executing 'clean build --offline'...

> Task :buildSrc:extractPluginRequests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:generatePluginAdapters UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:compileGroovy NO-SOURCE
> Task :buildSrc:compileGroovyPlugins UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:jar UP-TO-DATE

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Lenovo02\Documents\Workplace\Java\App\build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.graalvm.buildtools.native', version: '0.9.28'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (No included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.graalvm.buildtools.native:org.graalvm.buildtools.native.gradle.plugin:0.9.28')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    MavenLocal(file:/C:/Users/Lenovo02/.m2/repository/)
    maven(appartifactory/public_maven)
    maven2(appartifactory/public_maven2)
    maven3(appartifactory/public_maven3)

I tried to listen some advice here and there like downloading version 0.9.28 of org.graalvm.buildtools:native.maven.plugin or following the solution on this forum:
Is it possible to Install file to local cache in gradle similar to Maven install:install-file?
Which gave me a new build.gradle :
plugins {
    id 'org.graalvm.buildtools.native' version '0.9.28'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'app-sonar'
}

allprojects {
    group = 'app.project'
}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '8.7'
    distributionUrl = "gradle-${gradleVersion}-bin.zip"
}

configurations{
    resultArchives
}

uploadResultArchives{
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: mavenLocal().url)
            pom.version = '0.9.28'
            pom.artifactId= 'native-image-plugin'
            pom.groupId= 'org.graalvm.buildtools'
        }
    }
}

artifacts {
    resultArchives file: file('C:\\Users\\Lenovo02\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\org.graalvm.buildtools.native\\org.graalvm.buildtools.native.gradle.plugin\\0.9.28\\5046f95768b90b1b61b9daf9537503129850fc30\\org.graalvm.buildtools.native.gradle.plugin-0.9.28.pom')
}

Which gave me the same error.

If you haven't already, try running a complete build on your online computer, then copying the entire ~/.gradle directory over to your offline computer. Does it work then? Note if your online computer has run multiple different builds and you don't want to copy unnecessary things over, you can create a clean cache by setting GRADLE_USER_HOME to a different location for your session, then copy that directory instead.
